# CloudFunction access to MySQL hosted on Computer Engine Virtual Machine

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-vpc

My CloudFunction needs to access a MariaDB server hosted on a virtual machine from Computer Engine.

Accessing MariaDB by the public IP is working. But I want to access it from the private IP with VPC serverless connector. I don't want my database open on internet.

My VPC is configured with 10.10.0.0/28 adress range.

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYPZR.png)

My VM have 2 network interfaces :

- nic0 on default network : 10.132.0.12 and an external IP (34.XX.XX.XX)
- nic1 on vpc-subnet : 10.10.0.7

[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wc3DM.png)

CloudFunction is configured with the VPC connector.

[Screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hTqs.png)

My CloudFunction code :

```html
const mysql = require('mysql');
const ping = require('ping');
const config = require('./config.json');


exports.test = async function(event, context){
    //Decode data if is from pubsub call
    if(typeof event.data == "string"){
        var buff = new Buffer(event.data, 'base64');
        var data = JSON.parse(buff.toString('ascii'));
    }else{
        var data = event.data;
    }


    const db = mysql.createConnection({
        host: data.host,
        user: config.db.username,
        password: config.db.password,
        database: config.db.database
    });

    ping.sys.probe(data.host, function(isAlive){
        var msg = isAlive ? 'host ' + data.host + ' is alive' : 'host ' + data.host + ' is dead';
        console.log(msg);
    });

    db.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Connected to MySQL");

        db.query("Select * from Sites limit 1", function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
        });
    });

}
```

I tested 10.10.0.7 but I doesn't work.

Comment: can you share English version of snippet and also check if you are able to telnet on private IP.

Comment: Sorry for the french comments, i edited. Why method to telnet the private IP from the Cloud Function ? With NodeJS code ?

Comment: telnet means, telnet mariadb IP and port from where your NodeJS is running to check network connectivity issue or something else.

Comment: What's your error? What's your firewall rules?

Comment: My NodeJS is running on a CloudFunction, i will try telnet-client for NodeJS

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I got a timeout. It seems that the cloud function can't join the database through the private IP/VPC

Comment: Are you able to reach your database on the public IP? On the NIC0?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes i can reach the database on NIC0. But for more security, I would like to reach the database by the internal IP. Only my cloudfunction will access this database.
About my firewall rules, i added this firewall rules on GCP : 
IP Range : 0.0.0.0/0 TCP:3306 Allow on VPC Network

Comment: Did you try to access to the database, through the public IP deployed on NIC1? I have the feeling that your database doesn't listen traffic on the NIC1

Comment: Hi @guillaumeblaquiere, I dit a complete check of all my infrastructure (VM, NICs, Firewall rules, routes...etc) and now it works. 
I realized that I didn't need the NIC1. My VPC connector was configured to access my VM on NIC0 and not NIC1. I openend correct ports on firewall too.